# When is the determinant negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can anyone tell me when the determinant of the following matrix is negative. Is there a way to tell without calculation? Are there any tell-tale signs that increase the probability?

$$\left|\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 0 & {a}^{2} & {b}^{2} & {c}^{2}\cr 1 & {a}^{2} & 0 & {C}^{2} & {B}^{2}\cr 1 & {b}^{2} & {C}^{2} & 0 & {A}^{2}\cr 1 & {c}^{2} & {B}^{2} & {A}^{2} & 0\end{matrix}\right| > 0$$

Thanks.

Comment: The $>0$ tells you that it's positive $\ddot\smile$

Comment: What are $a,b,c,A,B,C$?

Comment: This is the Cayley-Menger determinant for calculating volume of a tetrahedron, so it will be positive if the variables are the edge-lengths of a tetrahedron (in the right order).

Comment: An interesting paper about Cayley-Menger determinant: (https://fr.scribd.com/document/330299515/The-Cayley-Menger-Determinant-is-Irreducible-for-n-3)